# Applying custom request options for a remote SPARQL connector in dotNetRdf

Tags: c#, .net, sparql, dotnetrdf

I'm trying to add custom headers to the HTTP requsets a [SPARQL endpoint connector](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/api/html/T_VDS_RDF_Storage_SparqlConnector.htm) issues. The connector [can use](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/api/html/M_VDS_RDF_Storage_SparqlConnector__ctor_2.htm) a custom [remote endpoint](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/api/html/T_VDS_RDF_Query_SparqlRemoteEndpoint.htm), which inherits an [ApplyCustomRequestOptions](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/api/html/M_VDS_RDF_BaseEndpoint_ApplyCustomRequestOptions.htm) method I can override. Documentation for that method says

> [...] add any additional custom request options/headers to the request.

However my overridden method is never called (so my custom options are not applied, so I can't add the headers).

The following code works as expected, except that my `ApplyCustomRequestOptions` is never invoked:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using VDS.RDF.Query;
using VDS.RDF.Storage;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var endpointUri = new Uri("https://query.wikidata.org/sparql");

        var endpoint = new CustomEndpoint(endpointUri);

        using (var connector = new SparqlConnector(endpoint))
        {
            var result = connector.Query("SELECT * WHERE {?s ?p ?o} LIMIT 1");
        }
    }
}

public class CustomEndpoint : SparqlRemoteEndpoint
{
    public CustomEndpoint(Uri endpointUri) : base(endpointUri) { }

    protected override void ApplyCustomRequestOptions(HttpWebRequest httpRequest)
    {
        // This is never executed.
        base.ApplyCustomRequestOptions(httpRequest);
        // Implementation omitted.
    }
}
```

**Is this the correct way to use these methods? If it isn't, what is it?**

BTW this is dotNetRdf 1.0.12, .NET 4.6.1. I've tried multiple SPARQL endpoints, multiple queries (`SELECT` & `CONSTRUCT`) and multiple invocations of `SparqlConnector.Query`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug. I've found the problem and fixed it and submitted a PR. You can track the status of the issue here: https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/issues/103